# 3rd monitor in Ubuntu 18.04: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, xorg.conf

I've got a Dell XPS 15 9570 with a TB16 docking station. Ubuntu works fine with 3 monitors (1 built-in + two external). However, strange things appear when I add a 4th monitor.

The Ubuntu sysconfig recognizes the monitor. In Devices -> Displays I can see all 4 monitors listed in the drop-down. However, I can only activate (put the graphical switch on "ON") of maximum 3 of them. Trying to activate the 4th, I get:

```
gnome-control-c[18797]: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: 
No available CRTC for monitor 'SHP 0x148d' not found
```

I've researched this error, but didn't find anything reasonable. However, it has to be some hard-coded check somewhere?

I've seen there seem to be an 8192 pixel maximum virtual desktop size somewhere, but "glxinfo -l | grep GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE" returns 16384 in my system.

Comment: I have the Dell latitude 7450 + TB16 docking station running 3 monitors until Friday. Today (after updates and reboot) I could only get the screen to 2 monitors. Have you experienced any new problems with your setup?

Comment: I found out that I can have 3 external monitors if I disable the laptop display. This is kind of a workaround for me. But it's interesting, that you say this happened to you after an (Ubuntu? I suppose...) update. I'll have a look in the change log.